# Azure: Output not as expected in Blob Write

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to write output to a text file stored in my azure container.

Following is my woker role snippet for it :

```
            string copyTemp="";                                

            copyTemp += "hi" + "\n";                
            copyTemp += "hello" + "\n";                

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(copyTemp))
                return;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {                
                memoryStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(copyTemp), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(copyTemp).Length);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream); 
            }
```

Now, when i download and check my blob,the output doesn't feature a new line.

```
"hihello"
```

Does anyone have an idea,what's goin wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Environment.NewLine rather than adding "\n" to your strings?

It might just be that your "\n" is not a full new line in the place you are reading it.  In windows I believe you need a "\r\n" to get a proper new line character.

You can read about the differences between new line (\n) and carriage return (\r) and which systems use which on [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) but that clarifies h that windows uses a carriage return and a line feed to signify a new line.

So if you had downloaded your blob on a Mac or on Linux it probably would have displayed as you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot man,that worked.But can u xplain me,why wasnt usual "\n" working.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for C# is to use the static string property **Environment.NewLine**. You can use it for writing text content to files, to azure blobs, to console output, and you will never have to think whether it is **\n** or **\r\n**. In your case the code will be:

```
 string copyTemp="";                                

 copyTemp += "hi" + Environment.NewLine;                
 copyTemp += "hello" + Environment.NewLine;
```