# Uploading JSON String as file to Azure File Storage - linebreaks disappear

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I have a list of dicts in Python and want to upload it as a json-file to Azure File Storage. When I print the list locally the linebreaks exist. After uploading and manually checking the file on Azure File Storage I noticed that the linebreaks were non existent.

```
list_of_dicts = my_json_dicts
transformed_dict_str = '\n'.join([json.dumps(x) for x in list_of_dicts])

# print(transformed_dict_str) gives me the "dicts"/lines separated by linebreaks.

service.create_file_from_text(share_name, file_path, file_name.json, transformed_dict_str, encoding='utf-8')
```

Can anyone tell me why the uploaded file (when i open it in notepad after downloading manually via the browser interface of Azure) does not contain any linebreaks?

---

Edit:

When I write the string to a local path with the following code, the linebreaks still exist. So it must happen during the create_file_from_text function?

```
file = open("myjson.json", "w")
file.write(transformed_dict_str)
file.close()
```

Comment: Is it ok when check it via right click the azure file -> edit?

Comment: i suspect this has to do with newline character and utf-8 encoding, are you using linux? what python version?

Comment: Please refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228484/azure-output-not-as-expected-in-blob-write and follow @Ivan's solution.

Comment: python 3.7; local machine is windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `'\r\n'` instead of `'\n'` in your code.

I can reproduce your issue when use '\n', but works fine using '\r\n' (in notepad, there is linebreaks).

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! Can you explain why newline (\n) needs return (\r) as well in this setting?

Comment: hi @Cribber, you can take a look at this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821784/whats-the-difference-between-n-and-r-n) thread for the detailed explanation.